# Saving multiple plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have this code to produce multiple plots from all the text files in a folder. It runs perfectly fine and shows the plots but i cant work out how to then save them all.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import os

rootdir='C:\documents\Neighbors for each search id'

for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir):
 for file in files:
  f=open(os.path.join(subdir,file),'r')
  print file
  data=np.loadtxt(f)

  #plot data
  pl.plot(data[:,1], data[:,2], 'gs')

  #Put in the errors
  pl.errorbar(data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,3], data[:,4], fmt='ro')

  #Dashed lines showing pmRa=0 and pmDec=0
  pl.axvline(0,linestyle='--', color='k')
  pl.axhline(0,linestyle='--', color='k')
  pl.show()

  f.close()
```

I have previously used

```
fileName="C:\documents\FirstPlot.png"
plt.savefig(fileName, format="png")
```

but i think this just saves each graph into one file and overwrites the last one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you have to do is provide unique filenames. You could use a counter:

```
fileNameTemplate = r'C:\documents\Plot{0:02d}.png'

for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for count, file in enumerate(files):
        # Generate a plot in `pl`
        pl.savefig(fileNameTemplate.format(count), format='png')
        pl.clf()  # Clear the figure for the next loop
```

What I did:

- Create a template using python's [string formatting syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)
- Added a counter to the loop using the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).
- Used the counter and the template to generate a new filename for each plot.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. ive tried this method and its all working, but the plots are coming out blank. I used the pl.show() aswell, and they produced the right plot, just not the actual saving bit. any ideas?

Comment: @user1841859: I have no idea. Perhaps `pl.show()` is required before you can save it? I have not used `pylab` myself.

Comment: plt.show() cannot come before plt.savefig
You must save it first before showing it.

Comment: I thought this was working, but now realised for each file it is plotting and saving a new file, but each one contains data from all the previous plots with just the new data on top?

Comment: @user1841859: Ah, it's a singleton plot. The [API](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) points to a clear method `pl.clf()`, you'll need to call that each loop too.

Comment: that works great now thanks! its amazing how one little line can cause so much trouble!

Comment: is there a way to specify the figure you want to save?

Answer (score 0):

You’re doing the right thing to save the plot (just put that code before `f.close()`, and make sure to use `pl.savefig` rather than `plt.savefig`, since you import `pyplot` as `pl`). You just have to give each output plot a different filename.

One way to do this is to add a counter variable that gets incremented for each file you go through, and add that to the filename, for instance, doing something like this:

```
fileName = "C:\documents\Plot-%04d.png" % ifile
```

Another option is to make a unique output filename based on the filename of the input. You could try something like:

```
fileName = "C:\documents\Plot-" + "_".join(os.path.split(os.path.join(subdir,file))) + ".png"
```

That will take the input path, and replace any path separators with `_`. You can use this as a part of your output filename.