# Python: Keep savefig from overwriting old plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, operating-system

I simply use

```
plt.savefig(filename+'.png', format='png')
```

to save my plots. But I want to keep my old versions of `filename.png` when I create a new one (using different colour codes, etc.) without always having to come up with a new filename.

Since I don't do that in one run, [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555069/saving-multiple-plots) doesn't help me. I found [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348026/how-do-i-create-a-file-in-python-without-overwriting-an-existing-file) on how to keep Python from overwriting files, but that's for `os`. Is there a way to do this with `savefig`?

In the end I want Python to check whether `filename.png` exists and only if so, save the new figure as `filename1.png`, `filename2.png`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to provide some unique name yourself: matplotlib won't do it for you. Nor will matplotlib check for existence of your current filename.
I would write a loop along the following lines:

(untested code)

```
import os
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    newname = '{}{:d}.png'.format(filename, i)
    if os.path.exists(newname):
        continue
    plt.savefig(newname)
    break
```

Note: if the extension is already `.png`, you don't need to set the format to `png` explicitly.

**Edit**

I realized the above is too long-winded, and only came about because I wanted to avoid doing the string formatting twice. The following is probably more logical:

```
import os
i = 0
while os.path.exists('{}{:d}.png'.format(filename, i)):
    i += 1
plt.savefig('{}{:d}.png'.format(filename, i))
```