# Plot multiple csv files with Python/matplotlib loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, matplotlib

I have a directory filled with multiple .csv files, each only has two columns (date and an integer). **I am trying to get this code to loop over each file and plot them individually so that there is a corresponding .png to each .csv**. Every time it runs, I end up with the correct number of .png files, but each has exactly the same data. I have already inplemented the `plt.clf()` method to clear it for each loop, but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as DT
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import scipy
import os
import glob

rootdir='/path/to/file'

for infile in glob.glob( os.rootdir.join(rootdir, '*.csv.out') ):
    output = infile + '.out'

data= np.loadtxt(infile, delimiter=',',
         dtype={'names': ('date', 'session'),'formats': ('S10', 'i4')} )

#Organizes 2-column spreadsheet
dates, sessions = map(list, zip(*data))
print dates, sessions

x = [DT.datetime.strptime(date,"%m-%d-%y") for date in dates]
y = [sessions]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.grid()
#Fills space under plotted line
ax.fill_between(x, sessions, color='blue')

# slants the x axis
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(x,sessions)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Sessions')
plt.title('Peak Usage')

fileNameTemplate = r'\path\to\file\Plot{}.png'

for subdir,dirs,files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for count, file in enumerate(files):
        pl.savefig(fileNameTemplate.format(count), format='png')
        pl.clf()
```

I modeled the enumerator after a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13555167/5174926) but I am still getting an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- define a function for your plots
- call that function from your loop
- include plt.close() at the end of said function.

Right now, you're not creating new plots as you walk the directory. The plot command needs to be inside the loop.

```
def plot():
   #do your plotting in here. If this is being called from a loop and the 
   #variables used herein are defined before, it will use the 
   #global values as they exist at the time. You can also end this function with
  fig.savefig(**args)
  plt.close()



for count, file in enumerate(files):
    plot()
```

Comment: So the function would envelop all the `plot.` pieces, correct? Or would it also take `data` as a variable or an argument?