# Python saving images with savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I am trying to save images to my computer obtained with savefig. Here is the code :

```
fig=plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
fig.savefig('filename.jpg')
```

But I have 200 files. I want to save these images with filename1.jpg, filename2.jpg.....,filename200.jpg. So, each time I want to change the filename. How can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555069/saving-multiple-plots

Answer (score 0):

Plot and save in a cycle:

```
for i in range(200):
   fig=plt.gcf()
   plt.show()
   fig.savefig('filename_{0:03d}.jpg'.format(i))
```

And you do not need `plt.draw` after `plt.show`. And you can save figure without showing.